# Renew SSL certificate after expiration on domain, which is accessible using a VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am new DevOps Engineer in the project and SSL certificates expired. We access this domain test.[smth].[smth].com through vpn, not accessible publicly. When I renew certificate, I have error. This should be caused by the fact mentioned above.

```
Found the following certs:
  Certificate Name: test.[smth].[smth].com
    Serial Number: 3ce2da614202d3d4684ca587945c4dc7bfa
    Key Type: RSA
    Domains: test.[smth].[smth].com
    Expiry Date: 2022-12-18 06:28:25+00:00 (INVALID: EXPIRED)
    Certificate Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/[smth].[smth].com/fullchain.pem
    Private Key Path: /etc/letsencrypt/live/[smth].[smth].com/privkey.pem
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
+ ssh centos@${!BITBUCKET_BRANCH} "sudo certbot renew"
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/test.[smth].[smth].com.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Non-interactive renewal: random delay of 471.892279475 seconds
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org
Renewing an existing certificate for test.[smth].[smth].com
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for test.examo.quantori.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain test.examo.quantori.com
http-01 challenge for test.examo.quantori.com
Cleaning up challenges
Failed to renew certificate test.examo.quantori.com with error: Some challenges have failed.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
All renewals failed. The following certificates could not be renewed:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.examo.quantori.com/fullchain.pem (failure)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1 renew failure(s), 0 parse failure(s)
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:
   Domain: test.[smth].[smth].com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: 3.234.199.16: Fetching
   http://test.examo.quantori.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/SCs6BzGPE4aD7aSFO7SN5dJtj1V3XL2lkPHo-dhKe1E:
   Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address. Additionally, please check that
   your computer has a publicly routable IP address and that no
   firewalls are preventing the server from communicating with the
   client. If you're using the webroot plugin, you should also verify
   that you are serving files from the webroot path you provided.
Searching for test report files in directories named [test-results, failsafe-reports, test-reports, TestResults, surefire-reports] down to a depth of 4
```

tried renewing but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)

If you want to renew a certificate by using a HTTP challenge in LetsEncrypt, then the server needs to be accessible from the internet and the it also needs to be able to make connections from the server to the internet. This does not seem to be the case here.

If you have at least control of the public DNS of the domain, then you can use the DNS challenge - see [How can I get a Let's Encrypt certificate for a non-public facing server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/829443/how-can-i-get-a-lets-encrypt-certificate-for-a-non-public-facing-server).